# designing schema for huge tables in oracle

Tags: database-design, oracle11g, schema-design

I have a user table, transaction table and user_transaction table. the number of users is around 75,000 number of unique transactions possible in the application is about (rows in transaction table is between 1 and 3 million).
user_transaction is the join of the above two table storing which transaction users did at what dateand time.. SO this table is going to be huge for 1 year of data (we are going to purge the active data from the table and archive it after 1 year). We are expecting the count to be around 50- 60 million rows. This will be final data size at the end of the year.

I would say average size is about 30 million records.
Also a nightly import job updates all these tables and thats the only part when inserts are done in these tables, we only access data (use select queries) from our app.

What would be the best way to design the join table to make retrieval from the huge transaction table faster?We have added many fields in the table to denaormalize it and reduce joins, and have almost all data available only in the transaction and user_transaction table.

If we want to partition the table how do we go about partitioning? The application is used to query the more recent data most frequently.

We are thinking in terms of partitioning month wise the transaction table so we would have 1 table for each month..

Other option we were thinking of is have 7 tables each for 1 day of the week, but this is increasing the complexity of queries greatly, considering we are using hibernate.

How do we design the huge table of around 60 milion

**More Details as requested:**
I will have to make a diagram from the schema,here is some more info in the mean time: the relationships are not complex, its about 4 tables: users, transactions, users_transaction, resource table. user_transaction is the join table containing all other three tables id  and that's the one which is going to be huge, since it will have separate entries on each of these id and also separate entries based on timestamp. 
The number of users of the application right now is very less like <20. (but may grow in the future). 
The main consumers of the tables are: 
1) **weekly self audit reports** sent out as emails containing user activity details for past week from these tables. these are going to be sent (eventually) to like 75,000 users and generating report and sending out the email for 1 user currently takes around 1 minute (testing in pilot phase). we need to seriously improve performance on this to like less than 5 seconds per email. This is a back-end job which runs at night (should consume at most 3-4 hours)
2) **Dashboards** containing charts which show summarized view of the transaction from these tables. These queries run and summarize data based on various fields in a date range.
Hence we are planning to summarize the user_transactions table storing counts for each day (not including time) if all other fields are same (users id, resource id, resource_eventid, location). 
And partition these summary tables based on month. (one for each month)

**Thing to note:** the solution should be good for all databases (MySQL, DB2 etc..)and not just oracle.

Regards,
Priyank Devurkar

Comment: First off, a licensing question.  Have you licensed (or will you license) the partitioning option?  That is an extra cost option on top of the enterprise edition license.

Comment: Yes, we will be ready to do that if required, considering the client really need this tool and is willing to spend as much as possible for best appliance

Comment: I'd like to see a diagram of the tables as well as some business rules.  How many users are normally involved in a transaction.  Is there some limit?

Comment: I suspect your best solution will be specific to each database. In Oracle, you'd use partitioning.

Comment: May be a stupid question. But do you really have a M-N relationship between users and transactions ? i.e. For a give transaction, are there really more than 1 user ? coz if not , you don't need the M-N mapping table. You can store user id in the transaction table it self. Even if a transaction can have say 2 users , I would still recommend having simply 2 columns in the transactions table instead of the M-N user_transaction table. Also you most definitely need partitioning considering the amount of your data and its temporal nature.

Comment: I think there is currently a m-n relationship between user and transaction table. transaction is a unique resource/url accessed in the application and can be performed by every user of the application. Suppose we have 40 users - 60 users , that would still make the transaction table huge if we put user column there, hence we have the join table of user_transactions. As far as partitioning goes we have for now partitioned the data on monthly basis, so its not touching all user_transaction partitioned tables for recent data requests - which is the most frequently queried data.

Comment: See above comment - a transaction would typically be carried out by a single user (if not in this case please explain why!) Getting rid of the many to many relationship will make things much easier here. Yes the transaction table will be huge, but the structure will be simpler to query/insert/update which is what you should care about.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first things first.

1. A table with 30 million rows is not HUGE by Oracle standards.
2. Saying that you have 75,000 users implies that the database is not managing your user logins and there are perhaps a few roles that are dealing with the database.

Auditing...

Oracle has very powerful auditing features, so should look into those before you try and roll your own.

If you really want to roll your own then there is a 1-many relationship between users and transactions.  Now I use the term transactions very loosely here, since what you seem to want to do is record when user X does something to modify a table, or row in a table.

The simplest is thing to do is have whatever front end code you are using to the inserts into that table, eg:

insert into auditing table ( userID, Operation) values ( 'fred', 'udpated table payments and changed some column old value to new value' );

I would make a compound index of userID and a timestamp, so that if can be queried on those two columns as a single entity.  The table would look something like:

```
create table user_audit as 
(
user_id number,
action_timestamp systimestamp,
db_action clob
)

CREATE INDEX idx_user_audit_ia ON  user_audit (user_id,action_timstamp);
```

The effect of the compound index is to create almost a hash of the two keys and they are very very fast when you query by those two columns.

This single table will be very very fast for deletes and inserts.  You can make it even faster by:

- Not having a primary key constraint.
- Turning off logging for this table or table space it is in.
- Not having an FK back to the users table ( it really is pointless ).
- IF you have enough ram on the database machine, set it hold onto the cache buffers, but **ONLY** if you have enough ram or you will put the server into the tank.
- If you choose to partition choose you method only after **carefully** reading and **understanding** partitioning on Oracle.
- Make **sure** your table space is **BIG TABLE** when you define it since that will make sure you don't blow through the size limit ( on linux at least ) of a single file.

As to the rest of the databases you deal with will have their individual tuning issues, so each of these are a set of one off conditions that will fit one DB engine but not another.

Remember the unix motto at all times, do **one** thing and do it **well**.